# XSLT transform copy nodes according to their position

Tags: xslt, transform

Does anyone know how i can use xslt transform in order to copy node according to what number node they are?

For example:

I want to copy only the 2nd and 4th child nodes

Input XML:

```
<parent>
   <child> something 1 </child>
   <child> something 2 </child>
   <child> something 3 </child>
   <child> something 4 </child>
</parent>
```

Output XML:

```
<parent>
   <child> something 2 </child>
   <child> something 4 </child>
</parent>
```

I don't know what the content/attributes of the child nodes are i can only work with what number child node they are.

Thanks

Comment: Where will the numbers 2 and 4 come from? Will they be hard-coded in the stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, 2 and 4 are not hard coded i receive a list and create the appropriate xslt

Comment: I am afraid that's not at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question *as asked* is rather trivial:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="child[position()=2 or position()=4]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That was only an example, I don't know what the input xml look like i do know what the path to the child node is (could be child/call/record...) but the parent node can be anything (and i don't necessary know it)